# How to make the iteration in Nest work?

Tags: function-construction

I have a code like

```
size = 1;
NestList[size = size*.5; Composition[size*# &, f], x, 3]
```

> `{x,0.5 f[x],0.5 f[0.5 f[x]],0.5 f[0.5 f[0.5 f[x]]]}`

As the result,the `size` always is `0.5`.How to make the `size = size*.5` work?I think the `Composition` have took effect the process.If I want to reserve the `Composition`,how to adjust my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NestList` does not hold its arguments so the `size` update occurs only once.  I suppose you want something like this:

```
size = 1;
NestList[Composition[(size = size*.5; size*#) &, f], x, 3]

(*  {x, 0.5 f[x], 0.25 f[0.5 f[x]], 0.125 f[0.25 f[0.5 f[x]]]}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks very very much..This logic cost my much time..

Answer (score 1):

You can get more functional-style code using `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[(#2 f[#1]) &, x, 1/2.^Range[3]]
```

> ```
> {x, 0.5 f[x], 0.25 f[0.5 f[x]], 0.125 f[0.25 f[0.5 f[x]]]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks,and actually I want to keep my `Composition`.